# Minimize application android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, authentication, minimize

I wrote an application with login/logout logic.
After login(set user and pass as vars) the user can minimize the application.

Minimize code:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
```

When user clicks on the app icon in first activity I check is have set user and pass as vars, if they are app go to activity 2(next activity).
if they are not set go to login interface.

Everything is working fine but sometimes the app forgets the user and pass after minimizing and I go to the login interface....

Is like clearing cache I don't know... help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use sharedPreferance to store login user and password.
below is code

```
private void storeUserPreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("username", "xyz");
                editor.putString("pass", "123");
        editor.commit();
    }


private void loadUserPreferences() {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
             String pass =sharedPreferences.getString("pass","");
             String username=sharedPreferences.getString("username","");
             if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(username))
             {
                login.....success
             }
             else
             {
                  redirect to login screen
               }



        }
```

this is ref doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: I'm not sure you want to put this in shared preferences. It would be the proper solution if the credentials it is storing are for another system (e.g. if your app uses Facebook you could store the Facebook details in the shared preferences). But if the purpose is to protect your app with a password that the user has to enter whenever they start it (but not when they just minimize it) then this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, you cannot assume that your application will be kept in memory when it goes to the background, and you cannot assume it stays on the foreground (people may press the Home key or popups may come up). You should implement the `onPause` and `onResume` events and store the details of the logged in user there. These methods are guaranteed to be called by Android whenever your application goes into the background and is re-activated, respectively. You can use the SavedBundle object that you get in these methods to store your data. Also read about the app lifecycle here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: SavedBundle is useful for keeping data between screen rotations but I think the OP will have to store data some other way in this case, e.g. via `SharedPreferences` or SQLite.

Comment: Thanks @Piovezan, I think I am not entirely clear on the question - see also my comment to Hardik's post below.

Comment: Hm after i set user and pass i mast put activity onPause?